# PHP function - compare with the following examples

Tags: php

1. compare with the two similar examples and please tell me why?
2. please explain it clearly.

   ```
   function inc(&$value, $amount = 1) {
       $value = $value + $amount;
       echo $value;    //21
   }

   $val = 20;
   inc($val); 
   echo "<br>$val";   //21

   echo "<hr>";

   function incSec(&$value, $amount = 1) {
       $value = $value + $amount;
       echo $value;    //21
   }

   incSec($valSec = 20);   
   echo "<br>$valSec";    //20
   ```

I'm trying to test, but can't get the reason.

Comment: Please format/indent your code to make it easily-readable

Comment: what are you trying to test, and what are you not getting?

Answer (score 6):

First, the second example you posted will output the other way around: "21" inside the function and "20" in the main body - test it yourself.

Now, for the exlanation...  To start with, the increment amount will always be 1, because you're not passing an explicity amount into the function.

In the first example, you assign a value to the variable, then pass that variable into a function by reference and in the function you increment the value.  The function will receive parameter "20", inrement it by a (default) amount of 1 and prints the result - "21".  After the function returns, the value (as it was passed by reference) is now incremented - and another "21" is printed.

In the second example, you assign 20 to your variable and pass into the function the result of that assignment.  The result will be 20, but it will be a different location in memory.  From the point of view of the function, it just receives a by-ref parameter with value 20, increments it and prints the result - hence you get "21".  When the function returns, you then print the value of your variable - which never was passed into the function (and therefore never incremented) - hence you get "20" printed.

Answer (score 0):

Suspect you're getting an error with these lines:

```
incSec($valSec = 20);
```

This isn't passing $valSec to the function, it's passing the **result** of the assignment of 20 to $valSec (typically a succesful assignment). The value of that result is 20 (assuming success), but it isn't a variable, it's merely a result.

Your incSec function() is defined to expect a variable passed by reference, but you can only reference a variable, not a result.

Comment: There will be no error in the call.  PHP will effectively assign the result of the assignment into a variable-with-no-name and pass that variable-with-no-name into the function by reference (in other words, it will save the result of assignment into a memory location and pass the address of that memory location into the function).  After the function returns, the value stored in that memory location is simply discarded.

Comment: You might get: "Strict standards: Only variables should be passed by reference in C:\xampp\htdocs\a.php on line 20" dependent on version of PHP

Comment: Possibly, but it would only be a warning.  I tested that code and didn't even get that (php 5.3.8 on mac os x)